# I am working on a Nextjs (App Router) application whereby I am using next-auth. I have integrate Azure AD B2C as an auth provider

Tags: next.js, azure-ad-b2c, next-auth

I configured my application based on next-auth docs, however when I try routing to the signin page and authenticating, I get this next-auth error on the url - "https://next-auth.js.org/errors#signin_oauth_error".

[image].

When I check on my terminal, I get more details about the error as below:

Here is the stack trace:

```
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#signin_oauth_error expected 200 OK, got: 404 Not Found {
  error: {
    message: 'expected 200 OK, got: 404 Not Found',
    stack: 'OPError: expected 200 OK, got: 404 Not Found\n' +
      '    at processResponse (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/openid-client@5.6.4/node_modules/openid-client/lib/helpers/process_response.js:37:15)\n' +        
      '    at Issuer.discover (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/openid-client@5.6.4/node_modules/openid-client/lib/issuer.js:142:22)\n' +
      '    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)\n' +
      '    at async openidClient (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/next-auth@4.24.6_next@13.5.5_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/oauth/client.js:12:18)\n' +
      '    at async getAuthorizationUrl (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/next-auth@4.24.6_next@13.5.5_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/oauth/authorization-url.js:88:20)\n' +
      '    at async Object.signin (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/next-auth@4.24.6_next@13.5.5_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/signin.js:21:30)\n' +
      '    at async AuthHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/next-auth@4.24.6_next@13.5.5_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:259:36)\n' +
      '    at async NextAuthRouteHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/next-auth@4.24.6_next@13.5.5_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:50:30)\n' +
      '    at async NextAuth._args$ (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/next-auth@4.24.6_next@13.5.5_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:85:24)\n' +
      '    at async D:\\PhpstormProjects\\AlternateLtd\\moti\\moti-frontend\\node_modules\\.pnpm\\next@13.5.5_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\compiled\\next-server\\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:62499',
    name: 'OPError'
  },
  providerId: 'azure-ad-b2c',
  message: 'expected 200 OK,
```

*Package versions:*

"next": "13.5.5",
"next-auth": "^4.24.6",

Here is my code snippet.

`api\auth\[...nextauth]\route.ts`

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import AzureADB2CProvider from "next-auth/providers/azure-ad-b2c";

if (
  !process.env.AZURE_B2C_TENANT_ID ||
  !process.env.AZURE_B2C_TENANT_NAME ||
  !process.env.AZURE_B2C_CLIENT_ID ||
  !process.env.AZURE_B2C_CLIENT_SECRET ||
  !process.env.AZURE_B2C_PRIMARY_USER_FLOW ||
  !process.env.NEXT_AUTH_SECRET
) {
  throw new Error("Auth required env variables are not set");
}

export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    AzureADB2CProvider({
      tenantId: process.env.AZURE_AD_B2C_TENANT_NAME as string,
      clientId: process.env.AZURE_B2C_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_B2C_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
      primaryUserFlow: process.env.AZURE_B2C_PRIMARY_USER_FLOW as string,
      authorization: { params: { scope: "offline_access openid" } },
      checks: ["pkce"],
      client: {
        token_endpoint_auth_method: "none",
      },
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.NEXT_AUTH_SECRET,
};

export const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

Answer (score 0):

For the next-auth to correctly navigate to the Azure AD B2C sign-in/signup form, I had to add a "wellKnown" property to AzureADB2CProvider and it worked

[image: azureb2c_signup_signin_form]

To get this wellKnown property,

1. Navigate to your Azure > Azure AD B2C > User flows,
2. Select your user flow, for my case it was B2C_1_Signup_SignIn, click on the Run User flow,

[image: azure_ad_b2c_user_flows]

3. A drawer will pop up, right below you have a link, copy it and paste it and add it to your AzureADB2CProvider options, as wellKnown as shown below:

[image: azure_ad_b2c_signin_signup_user_flows]

4. Add the link from above to your AzureADB2CProviders options in route.ts as shown in the snippet below:

```
providers: [
    AzureADB2CProvider({
      ...,
      wellKnown: https://${process.env.AZURE_B2C_TENANT_NAME}.b2clogin.com/${process.env.AZURE_B2C_TENANT_NAME}.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=${process.env.AZURE_B2C_PRIMARY_USER_FLOW},
     ...
        }),]
```